# Find a string not surrounded by a BBcode using Regex

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I am in need of a regular expression that will find, and replace, a word/phrase in a string only if it's not in an [url] BBcode.

```
$string = "Word [url='http://domain.com']Word test[/url]";
```

The regex should not do anything with "Word test", only the first occurrence of "Word".

EDIT: To be more specific, this is an addon for a forum software that monitors the messages for mentions of artists. If one occur, the artist's name is replaced with an URL to a thread about that artist, unless it's not already part of an URL (either in the link itself or the desc). After a second thought, it shouldn't be triggered if it's used in any tags that isn't pure markup (b,i,u,color,lists, etc). So an easy way to define what tags *can* be in to be replaced would be brilliant!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$inputStr = "Coldplay [URL='localhost/threads/coldplay-paradise.32/']Coldplay - \"Paradise\"[/URL] Coldplay";

function replace( $matches ) {
    if( isset( $matches[2] ) && $matches[2] )
        return "[url='coldplay']".$matches[2]."[/url]";
    return $matches[0];
}

$regex = '/(\[.*?\].*?\[\/.*?\])?(Coldplay)?(.+?)?/si';
$outputStr = preg_replace_callback( $regex, 'replace', $inputStr );
echo $outputStr;
```

result:

```
[url='coldplay']Coldplay[/url][URL='localhost/threads/coldplay-paradise.32/']Coldplay - "Paradise"[/URL] [url='coldplay']Coldplay[/url]
```

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't get that to work. With the following string "Coldplay [URL='http://localhost/threads/coldplay-paradise.32/']Coldplay - "Paradise"[/URL]
Coldplay", the result was "[url='http://coldplay']Coldplay[/url][url='http://coldplay'][/url]...". To be more specific, this is an addon for a forum software that monitors the messages for mentions of artists. If one occur, the artist's name is replaced with an URL to a thread about that artist, unless it's not already part of an URL (either in the URL itself, or the desc.

Comment: @Martin I don't know what you did wrong, I used your data and got the correct result, see above.

Comment: As this will look for more than one artist, the issue came when several different artists where mentioned in the message. Think I'm going to try a different approach to this using strpos(), substr() and substr_replace().

Comment: @martin You can easily incorporate multiple artists into this solution.